# Jquery ajax default success function with custom function

Tags: jquery, ajax

What I wanna do is have a default success function which all requests will go through and then a specific function with stuff for individual calls.

Something like

```
function handleResponse(data, func){
    if(data.error){
        display error information
    }else{
        func(data)
    }
}

$.ajax({
    success: handleResponse(data, function(){
        Individual request callback function
    })
});
```

Not quite sure if that would work by itself but I am writing this so you can understand the logic of what I'm aiming to do. What I want to ask is if there is a way I could pass this `handleResponse` function in `$.ajaxSetup` or something so I can just handle ajax response like I would normally with just a single anonymous function and have `handleResponse` be called automatically?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When jQuery calls your success handler it isn't expecting to pass it a function like that, but you can do something like the following:

```
function makeResponseHandler(func){
    return function(data) {
       if(data.error){
          // display error information
       }else{
          func(data);
       }
    };
}

$.ajax({
    success: makeResponseHandler(function(){
        //Individual request callback function
    })
});
```

The line with `success: ...` calls the `makeResponseHandler()` function immediately, passing it your individual anonymous function. The `makeResponseHandler()` function then returns another function and it is that function that becomes the success callback.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks! :P Gonna wait a while before I accept the answer tho

Comment: `success` functions are _so_ 2010 ;-)

Answer (score 2):

IMHO, the best way to do this is to use "deferred" objects, along with a function that will *pre-process* your AJAX results before passing them to your own callbacks:

```
function errorCheck(data) {
    if (data.error) {
        // display errors
        ...
        return $.Deferred().reject();  // "fake" a failure
    } else {
        return arguments;
    }
}
```

with usage:

```
$.ajax(...).then(errorCheck).done(function(data) {
    // normal callback function processing
    ...
}).fail(function() {
    // called if AJAX fails, or if data.error is set
    ...
});
```

This allows you to decide on a per-call basis whether you want to use the `errorCheck` logic or not, and also allows use of `errorCheck` with `$.get`, `$.post` etc.

Comment: This just looks so complicated about doing something that simple :/ +rep of course but I'd rather go with simplicity, even though it may be 2010 :D

Comment: @php_nub_qq actually I just simplified it somewhat - I found the right way to make `.then` return a "failure" to replace a "success".

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/path/",
    success: handleResponse
});
```

Comment: I don't see how that handles individual anonymous functions :/

Answer (score 0):

Why not ?

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/path/",
    success: function(data){
       handleResponse(data, function(){
       });
    }
});

function handleResponse(data, callback){
   if(data.error){
      display error information
   }else{
      callback.call();
   }
}
```

Comment: `callback.call()`? You know you can just say `callback()`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think anything like this exists already, but you could qrap the ajax call in something like

```
function doAjax(url, callback) {
  $.ajax({
    url: "/path/",
    success: function (...) {
      handleResponse();
      callback();
    }
  });
}
```

> doAjax("/path", function () { .. } );

Comment: I think this may get awfully painful if I need to use more of `$.ajax`'s properties locally

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ajaxcomplete(function(){
//This function is executed on every ajax call completion.
});
```

Then you simply do your request as you would...

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/path/",
    success: function(){
        //My handler for this call.
    }
});
```

You can read more at http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/

Comment: Yeah but that way the success function will be called no matter what the response is. I have custom error handling which sends an error property of the response object if something went wrong and if it is present I need to abort the callback

Comment: then replace the ajaxcomplete for ajaxsuccess... I myself use ajaxcomplete to track errors and send them somewhere else but multiple options are open to you.

Comment: @php_nub_qq FWIW, RESTful style services _should_ indicate an error with a `4xx` style response code, triggering the "AJAX error" path, rather than a `2xx` indicating a "success".

Answer (score 0):

Its the simple way to do common ajax validations.

```
$.ajax({
   success: function(data){
                alert("Hi");
//DO WHATEVER VALIDATIONS YOU WANT TO DO HERE
                ajaxPostSuccess(data);
            }
});

function ajaxPostSuccess(data){
//DO THE REMAINING HERE
}
```